# Jquery change Content link value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a group of divs and a next button.

```
<div class="check" id="a1"> ... </div>
<div class="check" id="a2"> ... </div>
<div class="check" id="a3"> ... </div>
 ...
<div class="check" id="an"> ... </div>
<a href="#some-div" id="next">Next</a>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
jQuery( "#next" ).click(function() {
 // filter function 
});
```

So when I try to link the address bar value would be `http://myhost.com#some-div`
Is it possible that I can change it into `http://myhost.com#a2` withount changing the `#next` href value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
jQuery( "#next" ).click(function() {
 // filter function 
   location.hash="a2";
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery( "#next" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  location.hash = "a2"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#next").click(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           location.hash = "a2"
       });
```